# order_by causing not distinct items

Tags: django

I've implemented a messaging system:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, related_name = 'messages')
    conversation = models.ForeignKey('Conversation', related_name = 'messages')

    body = models.TextField(max_length=750)
    reads = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_messages', null=True, blank=True)

    # Other
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True)

class Conversation(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='conversations')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="D", choices=config.CONVERSATION_TYPE_OPTIONS)
```

Using Django Rest Framework, I'd like to order a conversation by the last message.

```
class ConversationFilter(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    """
    Filters to only show by current user
    """
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            participants=request.user,
        ).order_by('-messages__date_created')
```

However once I add the `order_by` method, the queries are no longer distinct. Adding `distinct()` does not work either. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a one to many relationship between Conversation and Message.

When you join the message table into the Conversation query (which happens when you add the order_by clause using messages), then you will get multiple Conversation entries, one for each message.